# hyphenation - non breaking hyphen - wrong result in some cases - iText 7.1.0 for Java

Tags: itext7

At the moment I'm writing a couple of evaluatuation programs with iText.

There is an issue with Hyphenation.

We need the non breaking hyphen \u2010 which does'nt work properly in some
cases.

[image: screenshot of PDF]

There should be no line break between "99" and "Tage" or "99" and "Frage".
Only "99-Days" works as expected!

I hope someone out there has an idea what could be the reason for that and what could be done.

The code below needs a correct path to arialuni.ttf.

Thanks a lot in advance! Dirk

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Text;
import com.itextpdf.layout.hyphenation.HyphenationConfig;

public class problem1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fnFont = "src/main/resources/fonts/arialuni.ttf";
        String fnPdf = "results/problem1.pdf";
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fnPdf);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        Text text = new Text(
                "Dies ist ein Satz in deutscher Sprache. An hm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind. Und der Umbruch? 99\u2011Tage-Kaiser.\n"
                        + "Dies ist ein Satz in deutscher Sprache. An hm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind. Und der Umbruch? 99\u2011Days-Kaiser.\n"
                        + "Dies ist ein Satz in deutscher Sprache. An hm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind. Und der Umbruch? 99\u2011Frage-Kaiser.\n");
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fnFont, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
        text.setFont(font);
        text.setFontSize(10);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(text);
        paragraph.setHyphenation(new HyphenationConfig("de", "DE", 2, 2));
        document.add(paragraph);
        document.close();
        pdf.close();
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(fnPdf));
        }
}
```

Comment: The reason is that iText7 layout does not support non-breaking hyphen yet which requires separate logic that differs from everything else.

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for this info! Do you know if there is a possibility for a workaround? Have you any idea? Dirk

Comment: @Dirk Kampfmeier I just want to notify you that the problem has been fixed. The changes will be introduced in the very new release (july)